# Advanced Skype functions with Skype URIs

Tags: voip, skype

I'd like to make a Windows 8 app that tightly integrates with Skype but I'm fearing I may be too late. I'd like it to do such things as:

- Login to a user's Skype account
- Get all contacts of the logged in user with their account pic
- Allow the user to initiate a call to any of their contacts

I understand that Skype URI's will allow me to do item #3 but what about the first two? All indications are that everything except the URI's will be decommissioned at the end of the year. And even if I wanted to make something that would work until that point, I can't find any documentation on the C# or JavaScript API, just an FAQ about what it is and how long it will be around.

Will the Skype platform allow me to do what I'm looking for and if not, is there a good alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Skype platform does not allow you to perform login which is always user initiated action (password).

SkypeKit API (C#) allows you to retrieve contact list from a running Skype application, after the user authorization. You can also use this API to initiate a call.

The SkypeKit API is deprecated and Microsoft is pulling the plug on it. I suggest you consider moving to some platform where you have guaranteed API availability.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17708758/alternatives-for-deprecated-net-skypekit